VS Code don]t open
My vs code opens and then closes abruptly. I have Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
[0607/224759.883007:ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)] read out of range

I deleted vs code.
I delete vs code and update driver

Not much anybody here can do other than suggest you delete settings or get logs.  If you have assignments, use an alternate editor in the meantime.
